# How can I create a custom View with a Relative Size?

Tags: android, android-view

I would like to design an application which could work with devices of any screen resolution.

My idea to do so was to create one Custom View for each type of View I use, and use the `layout_width` and `layout_height` specified in the XML as a percentage of the parent size (for example, `layout_width="100dp"` is equivalent to `fill_parent`, and `layout_width="50dp"` means the `View`'s width will be half the parent's one).

Here is the custom `TextView` class I made:

```
public class RSTextView extends TextView {

    public RSTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int w, int h) {
        int parentWidth = ((View)this.getParent()).getWidth();
        int parentHeight = ((View)this.getParent()).getHeight();
        Log.i(null, "Width: " + w + "; Height: " + parentHeight);
        this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth * MeasureSpec.getSize(w) / 100,
                parentHeight * MeasureSpec.getSize(h) / 100);
    }
}
```

However, it does not work. The `parentWidth` and `parentHeight` size is always 0.

Is there any better way to create an application with a relative size?

And if it is the right way to go, how can I retrieve the `View`'s parents' size from the `onMeasure` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're checking a view's height during the layout phase, you probably want to be using [`getMeasuredHeight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight%28%29), not `getHeight`, but I'm not sure you need to be doing what you're doing at all. It's hard to tell from your description, but it seems like you might be trying to recreate the behavior of [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout) weights. For example, if you have a horizontal `LinearLayout` with 3 children, you can easily set the first to take up half its width and the others each to take up 25% by assigning them `0px` `layout_width`s and `layout_weight`s of 2, 1 and 1 respectively (or any other weights of those proportions).

If you do decide to go the custom `View` route, though, don't overload what `layout_height` and `layout_width` do -- use custom XML attributes to take the argument for the percentages (I'd dig into `LinearLayout`'s code to see how `layout_weight` is implemented).

Comment: Thanks!
Well, the problem is that layout_weight only works with LinearLayout, and not with RelativeLayout.

But I'm confused, what is the best way to write applications that work with devices of any size?

Comment: Google's reccomendations: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence