# How can I get a popup to be a relative size?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want external links to open in a new window in a process that is obvious to the user so want the popup window to be a relative size to the parent window.  Initially I just used the target attribute but then started using something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.org"  
onclick="window.open(this.href,'window','width=810,height=480,location=0, resizable, scrollbars, toolbar=0, menubar=0') ;return false;">example.org</a>
```

But I can only get this to work with pixel values, and I want to make the popup's width and height relative to the devices screen size (%).
Seems simple enough, but I can't find anything online that simply explains how to do it.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
This is a boilerplate page:

```
<?php 
require("docHead.php"); 
?> this includes everything needed at the head of a document
<title>...</title> varies with the page
</head> 
<body>
<?php 
require("bannerMenu.php"); 
?> navigation etc
<div id="..">
  <div id="..">
        <h1>...</h1>
        <h2>...</h2> 
        Ipsum lorem etc <a href=.....>
        <?php
        require("footer.php"); 
        ?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Chris, well I've tried editing the expression to use % and that doesn't work, I've searched online for relevant information and not found anything helpful.  Any suggestions?  Maybe what I think is simple is actually complicated and I need to start somewhere else .. not sure what else to say. ps maybe the code I attached wasn't showing when you read the post - but I got that working at least (though isn't there a simpler way?)

Comment: e.g I've read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316019/how-can-i-create-a-custom-view-with-a-relative-size but don't understand it and think it may be talking about a different situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
Use javascript. window.inner/outer width/height

```
    <script>
        var features =' width=' + window.outerWidth/2 + ', height=' + window.outerHeight/2 + ',location=0, resizable, scrollbars, toolbar=0, menubar=0';
    </script>

<a href="https://example.org" onclick="window.open(this.href,'window', features) ;return false;">example.org</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrius, where in the document do I set the width=window.outerWidth, height=window.outerHeight values?

Comment: @talvi I added to your example width=window.outerWidth, height=window.outerHeight

Comment: Hiya!  What I meant was how do I make those values 50% say of the available screen or window?   I assume for instance that using just window.outerWidth as the variable sets the popup's width to 100% of the parent window's width?

Comment: Okay. Then use it like this.

<script>
    var features =' width=' + window.outerWidth/2 + ', height=' + window.outerHeight/2 + ',location=0, resizable, scrollbars, toolbar=0, menubar=0'; </script>
  @talvi  <a href="https://example.org" onclick="window.open(this.href,'window', features) ;return false;">example.org</a>

Create variable with your window features. There you can set window.outerWidth/2

Comment: Great Andrius, so the script sets the values for a variable called `features` and also includes the other variables I was using for the `<a>` tag e.g menubar?  Then this variable is attached to the `onclick` parameters `window.open(this.href,'window',FEATURES` ?  Do I read it correctly?  The site uses a modular design with `php require` statements.  Must the script be placed somewhere special in the documents?

Comment: Yes. Correct.
If you can copy your code, maybe I could help you more.
Because now, I gave an example of how it works.

Comment: Hi Andrius, I 've attached an elemental boilerplate fwiw to my OP.  In the `<?php require("docHead.php"); ?>` is included the link to the CSS file plus any `<script>...</script>` that I'd want to apply.  Would yours go in there?  I ask only because Luddens Desir asked for theirs to be attached at the very end of the `body`.

Comment: You can add <script>...</script> in your docHead.php or before </body> closingtag.
It will work both ways. But proper one would be to set it before </body> closing tag.

Comment: Thanks Andrius, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');

testDiv.onclick = function(){
    var xVal = .5 * window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var yVal = .5 * window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    window.open('http://google.com','Title','width = ' + xVal + ',' + ' height = ' + yVal );
};
```

Comment: Hi Luddens Desir, thanks for all that.  I'm using the javascript only because the target attribute can't do what I want but really I only know HTML and CSS.  Where/how do I insert the code you suggest into the document?  It looks a bit beyond my abilities :(

Comment: At the bottom of your document before your closing body tag just insert a couple of <script> </script> tags with the code inside. if you're not using jQuery, which is library of pre-written js code that makes manipulating the documents easier, just use the noJQ code I mentioned above. I removed the jQuery code then modified the code so that it represents code that is tested and is working on my end. :)

Comment: Sorry to be dumb but I don't get this.  Anyway I did as I thought you suggested (cut and pasted the code above into the body of a document substituting only the URL) but - well, there isn't a link in the document that can be addressed by the script so I guess I need to adapt the <a> tag so it finds the script that tells it to open that link in a half size window?  But how?

Comment: You need to surround the code in script tags in your html file before the closing tag for your body div. Made a short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctqtyCVmqsk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Wow that's a first for me.  Thanks!  Sadly for some reason I can't open it :(  But what you wrote is what I did.  
<script>
 var xVal = .5 * window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
 var yVal = .5 * window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight; 
 
 window.open('http://yourfavoritewebsite.com','Title','width = ' + xVal + ',' + ' height = ' + yVal );
</script>

Comment: In the document (used just for testing this) there are half a dozen links.  The code I end up using will be used for all external links throughout the site.

Comment: I was messing with the code for a while, so you probably didn't get it in a fixed state. Make sure you refresh the page and copy what I have up there, because what you just pasted back to me is missing the parts I added after realizing you don't normally use javascript.

Comment: The bit missing was the `var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');` right?  Your suggestion seems to be targetting a div element, rather than by an `<a>` tag, and identifying it by an `ID`.  How could it be changed so that it it selects the element by a class i.e `<a class="ExtLink">` .. actually is it even possible to have an `<a>` tag with a class?

Comment: Yes it was, yes you can. and I was targeting the entire banner in the video.